# How to get content area to expand down to footer with no body and html styling

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to find a way to have a div expand down to the footer even when its content isn't big enough, preferable with CSS but a React solution is welcome as well. It should scroll within itself without pushing down the footer, which is fixed at the bottom.

[image]

Currently I have the contentArea with the following CSS...

```
 position: sticky;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 height: 60vh; //this shouldn't be set, should just expand down to its sibling container, the footer, at the bottom
```

The container's parent has the `position:relative` styling.

There are similar solutions on here but they all require setting 100vh on the body, or styling the body in some way, and I can't do that as this is a standalone React component. The component starts at the blue dropdown, the one with `Step 1 of 5` in it

Comment: Can you provide some fiddle? It is rather easy to do but it depends on your structure and styling there. One solution would be to use `display: flex` with proper settings for one or multiple tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
.parentContainer {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.selectedContainer {
flex: 1;
}
```